# Remove spaces between two words ONLY

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, tr

I have the following

```
"/x/x y/asfas/g.pdf          " "fdfdf
"/x/y/yy    y/d.doc    " "fdfdf
etc..
```

I want to remove the spaces between the extension and the " ONLY

when I used `tr` to remove trailing space it removes the spaces in between that are more than 1 space (ex: `yy     y` becomes `yy y`)

Comment: Will that *always* be the *first whitespace* before the *second `"` character*?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
sed 's/\(\.[^"[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]]*"/\1"/g'
```

That is remove the sequences of blanks that follow `.` followed by a sequence of non-blank-nor-`"` characters and are followed by a `"`

To remove the blanks before every *other* double quote character on each line, you could do something like:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*"/"&/g
     s/\(\([^"]*"\)\{3\}\)[[:blank:]]*"/\1"/g
     s/"\([^"]*"\)/\1/g'
```

That is:

1. Insert an extra `"` before each `<blanks>"`
2. Change all the `<X>"<blanks>"<Y>"<blanks>"` to `<X>"<blanks>"<Y>""`
3. Remove every other `"` to undo the insertions in 1

Or in a more straightforward manner with `awk`:

```
awk -F \" -v OFS=\" '
  {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2 )
      sub(/[[:blank:]]*$/, "", $i)
    print
  }'
```

Note that `tr` wouldn't squeeze characters unless you use the `-s` option. More likely you forgot to quote a parameter expansion or command substitution that contained the output of `tr`.

In any case, `tr` can't be used for that task. It's just a transliteration tool. All it could do is translate/delete/squeeze *all* space characters. It cannot translate/delete/squeeze only *some* space characters.

Answer (score 1):

GNU ***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/\([^.]*\.[^."[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]\+"/\1"/' file
```

---

- `\([^.]*\.[^."[:space:]]*\)` - the 1st captured group containing hypothetical filename with extension
- `[[:space:]]\+"` - ensures at least one space between *extension* and `"`

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU sed. Search for one or more spaces, followed by a double quote. Replace that with a double quote:

```
sed -i -e 's/ \+"/"/' file
```

or like this, at your option:

```
sed -i -e 's/[[:space:]]\+"/"/' file
```

Comment: That would change `"foo.bar" "baz"` to `"foo.bar""baz"` though

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, if that pattern would occur. There is not that many samples in the question, so it is not clear to say.